# merge two rows into one row in sql?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table as :

| Serveur | Total | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #01 | 200 | 2022-01-01 14:11:50.000 |
| #01 | 100 | 2022-01-01 22:19:33.000 |
| #02 | 150 | 2022-01-01 14:55:35.000 |
| #02 | 300 | 2022-01-01 21:45:28.000 |
| #03 | 500 | 2022-01-01 21:43:21.000 |

But I want the output as follows(I want to use this output to inner join with some other table) :

| Serveur | Total_1 | Total_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #01 | 200 | 100 |
| #02 | 150 | 300 |
| #03 | 500 | 0 |

Comment: Hint : **conditional aggregation** which is a generic method to pivot for most of the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Microsoft SQL
Please follow the link below for syntax and examples on how to pivot the data within tables
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Or you can use sun queries to pivot which is time consuming and dirty way of doing it.